Complete orthonormal basis of divergence free vector fields
I'm working on a problem in fluid dynamics. I need to find a complete basis of orthonormal 3D vector fields. My "inner product" between vectors $\mathbf{v}_1$, $\mathbf{v}_2$ is a dot product followed by volume integration i.e $\langle \mathbf{v_1, v_2} \rangle = \iiint \mathbf{v_1}^\top\mathbf{v_2}dV$. The domain is a cuboid $[0, L_x] \times [0, L_y] \times [0, L_z]$.
These vector fields $\mathbf{v}(x, y, z)$ must be divergence free $\nabla\cdot \mathbf{v} =0$. Furthermore they have to be periodic in the $x$ and $z$ directions and vanish at the boundary in $y$. In equations $\mathbf{v}(x,y,z) = \mathbf{v}(x+L_x,y,z)$, $\mathbf{v}(x,y,z) = \mathbf{v}(x,y,z+L_z)$, and $\mathbf{v}(x,0,z) = \mathbf{v}(x,L_y,z)=0$.
I've tried a bunch of separation of variable type solutions using eigenfunctions of the Laplacian operator (sines and cosines). The boundary condition in the $y$ direction makes getting vectors with a non-zero $y$ component tricky. I've also looked at normal modes of the biharmonic equation as potential solutions. The issue with the biharmonic modes is then enforcing $\nabla\cdot \mathbf{v} = 0$ and orthogonality at the same time (it's easy to make the vectors divergence free but they are not orthogonal). I know Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization is an option but I'm hoping for something cleaner.
I'm wondering if this is a standard problem in some part of the mathematics literature that I am unaware of. Any pointers or fresh ideas are much appreciated. Thanks!

Perhaps applying the Leray projection to the basis of sines/cosines that satisfy your boundary conditions could be fruitful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leray_projection
